# Adding Column To Each Quantmod Symbol

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

Learning R, not sure how to solve this.

```
library(quantmod)
library(xts)

# get market data
Nasdaq100_Symbols <- c("AAPL", "AAL")
getSymbols(Nasdaq100_Symbols)

# merge them together
nasdaq100 <- data.frame(as.xts(merge(AAPL, AAL)))
#tail(nasdaq100[,1:12],2)

#make percent difference column
nasdaq100$PD <- (((nasdaq100$AAPL.High - nasdaq100$AAPL.Open)/nasdaq100$AAPL.Open) * 100)
```

I'm trying to add a percent difference column, but the above code will only work for the AAPL symbol (or whichever symbol you use) and not create a PD column for each symbol.

Do you have to add that column somehow before merging with xts, or can I tell R to create it for each symbol in the new merged frame?

*Edit:* I am doing data training, so I need all symbols to be headers, like:

```
           AAPL.Ope AAPL.High AAPL.Volume AAL.Open AAL.High

1/3/2007    86.29   86.58      309579900    53.89   56.92
1/4/2007    84.05   85.95      211815100    56.3    59.15
1/5/2007    85.77   86.2       208685400    58.83   59.15
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, it usually makes much more sense to keep your financial data as `xts` objects, for future manipulation with other technical indicators etc, unless you plan to run a prediction model in say `caret` in which case converting to a `data.frame` may make sense.

Consider keeping your symbols of data as elements of a container, such as

```
update_sym_md <- function(sym, env = .GlobalEnv) {
    x <- get(sym, env)
    pd <- setNames((Hi(x) - Op(x)) / Op(x), "PD")
    merge(x, pd)
}

# Adjust env for location of xts symbol data
l.syms <- lapply(Nasdaq100_Symbols, update_sym_md, env = .GlobalEnv)

lapply(l.syms, head)
# [[1]]
# AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted          PD
# 2007-01-03     86.29     86.58    81.90      83.80   309579900      10.85709 0.003360760
# 2007-01-04     84.05     85.95    83.82      85.66   211815100      11.09807 0.022605556
# 2007-01-05     85.77     86.20    84.40      85.05   208685400      11.01904 0.005013373
# 2007-01-08     85.96     86.53    85.28      85.47   199276700      11.07345 0.006630991
# 2007-01-09     86.45     92.98    85.15      92.57   837324600      11.99333 0.075534942
# 2007-01-10     94.75     97.80    93.45      97.00   738220000      12.56728 0.032190006
# 
# [[2]]
# AAL.Open AAL.High AAL.Low AAL.Close AAL.Volume AAL.Adjusted           PD
# 2007-01-03    53.89    56.92   53.89     56.30    2955600     54.80361 0.0562256273
# 2007-01-04    56.30    59.15   53.65     58.84    2614500     57.27610 0.0506217238
# 2007-01-05    58.83    59.15   57.90     58.29    1656300     56.74072 0.0054394015
# 2007-01-08    57.30    60.48   57.04     57.93    2163200     56.39028 0.0554974006
# 2007-01-09    59.44    60.20   57.56     57.90    2098600     56.36108 0.0127860366
# 2007-01-10    60.03    60.04   57.34     58.93    3892200     57.36371 0.0001666167
```

Also, if you do want to compare price returns/raw prices across symbols in one xts object, rather than in a data.frame, you might find the `qmao` package useful.

For example:

```
install.packages("qmao", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type = "source")
library(qmao)

pf <- makePriceFrame(Nasdaq100_Symbols)
head(pf, 3)
#               AAPL      AAL
# 2007-01-03 10.85709 54.80361
# 2007-01-04 11.09807 57.27610
# 2007-01-05 11.01904 56.74072
rf <- makeReturnFrame(Nasdaq100_Symbols)
head(rf)

#                  AAPL           AAL
# 2007-01-03           NA            NA
# 2007-01-04  0.021952895  0.0441273684
# 2007-01-05 -0.007146715 -0.0093913155
# 2007-01-08  0.004926208 -0.0061951917
# 2007-01-09  0.079799692 -0.0005179716
# 2007-01-10  0.046745798  0.0176329011
```

*Update in response to comment from OP:*

To join all the data into one row, try this:

(Aside: if you're going to use non linear prediction models on this data.frame, make sure you consider scaling your data points across securities in each row first.)

```
x.cbind <- do.call(cbind, l.syms)
head(x.cbind)
# AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted          PD AAL.Open AAL.High AAL.Low AAL.Close AAL.Volume AAL.Adjusted         PD.1
# 2007-01-03     86.29     86.58    81.90      83.80   309579900      10.85709 0.003360760    53.89    56.92   53.89     56.30    2955600     54.80361 0.0562256273
# 2007-01-04     84.05     85.95    83.82      85.66   211815100      11.09807 0.022605556    56.30    59.15   53.65     58.84    2614500     57.27610 0.0506217238
# 2007-01-05     85.77     86.20    84.40      85.05   208685400      11.01904 0.005013373    58.83    59.15   57.90     58.29    1656300     56.74072 0.0054394015
# 2007-01-08     85.96     86.53    85.28      85.47   199276700      11.07345 0.006630991    57.30    60.48   57.04     57.93    2163200     56.39028 0.0554974006
# 2007-01-09     86.45     92.98    85.15      92.57   837324600      11.99333 0.075534942    59.44    60.20   57.56     57.90    2098600     56.36108 0.0127860366
# 2007-01-10     94.75     97.80    93.45      97.00   738220000      12.56728 0.032190006    60.03    60.04   57.34     58.93    3892200     57.36371 0.0001666167

df.cbind <- data.frame("time" = index(x.cbind), coredata(x.cbind))
head(df.cbind)
# time AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted          PD AAL.Open AAL.High AAL.Low AAL.Close AAL.Volume AAL.Adjusted         PD.1
# 1 2007-01-03     86.29     86.58    81.90      83.80   309579900      10.85709 0.003360760    53.89    56.92   53.89     56.30    2955600     54.80361 0.0562256273
# 2 2007-01-04     84.05     85.95    83.82      85.66   211815100      11.09807 0.022605556    56.30    59.15   53.65     58.84    2614500     57.27610 0.0506217238
# 3 2007-01-05     85.77     86.20    84.40      85.05   208685400      11.01904 0.005013373    58.83    59.15   57.90     58.29    1656300     56.74072 0.0054394015
# 4 2007-01-08     85.96     86.53    85.28      85.47   199276700      11.07345 0.006630991    57.30    60.48   57.04     57.93    2163200     56.39028 0.0554974006
# 5 2007-01-09     86.45     92.98    85.15      92.57   837324600      11.99333 0.075534942    59.44    60.20   57.56     57.90    2098600     56.36108 0.0127860366
# 6 2007-01-10     94.75     97.80    93.45      97.00   738220000      12.56728 0.032190006    60.03    60.04   57.34     58.93    3892200     57.36371 0.0001666167
```

To better understand how `qmao` functions work, why not look at the examples in the documentation and go from there?
`?makeReturnFrame` Look at the source code to really understand what's going on (and become a better R programmer at the same time by learning good coding styles)

Comment: I am doing data training, so I do want all symbols to be at the top.  Can't really figure out how qmao works, I can only get it to pull that one data field.

Comment: @Alteredorange when you want all symbols at the top, I presume you mean you want data across securities in each column of the data frame, and each row is therefore one observation in a prediction model that uses cross-sectional security price data.  I've edited by answer to show one way to do this.

Comment: that seems to be just what I need! One more question, is there any way to name the column "symbol.PD", so they would be AAPL.PD and AAL.PD instead of PD and PD.1?

Comment: Not sure if this is the right way, but I used:  `actsym <- paste(sym,"pd")
  pd <- setNames(((Hi(x) - Op(x)) / Op(x))*100, actsym)` and it seems ot work!

Comment: @Alteredorange yep, that works just fine. Or, slightly more compactly `pd <- setNames((Hi(x) - Op(x)) / Op(x), paste0(sym, ".PD"))`

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add a solution using the quite new and interesting package `tidyquant` which is great for tasks like this. You can use all the stuff from tidyverse and on top it leverages the quantitative power of xts, quantmod and TTR ! Have a look at the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyquant/vignettes/tidyquant.html) with many examples.

```
library(tidyquant)
c("AAPL", "AAL") %>%
  tq_get(get = "stock.prices") %>%
  group_by(symbol.x) %>%
  tq_mutate(ohlc_fun = OHLCV, mutate_fun = OpCl,col_rename='diff') %>% 
  select(- c(low,volume)) # I deselect low and volume to show the added colum ‘diff'

Source: local data frame [5,110 x 7]
Groups: symbol.x [2]

   symbol.x       date  open  high close adjusted         diff
      <chr>     <date> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
1      AAPL 2007-01-03 86.29 86.58 83.80 10.85709 0.0033607603
2      AAPL 2007-01-04 84.05 85.95 85.66 11.09807 0.0226055559
3      AAPL 2007-01-05 85.77 86.20 85.05 11.01904 0.0050133730
4      AAPL 2007-01-08 85.96 86.53 85.47 11.07345 0.0066309913
5      AAPL 2007-01-09 86.45 92.98 92.57 11.99333 0.0755349424
```

UPDATE: question was asked to add symbols into column names

Assuming you saved the above data frame into variable `stocks`:

```
lapply(unique(stocks$symbol.x), function(x) stocks[stocks$symbol.x == x,]) %>% 
lapply( function(x) {
  names(x) <- paste0(x$symbol.x[1],'.',colnames(x))
  x
}) 
[[1]]
Source: local data frame [2,555 x 7]
Groups: symbol.x [1]

   AAPL.symbol.x  AAPL.date AAPL.open AAPL.high AAPL.close
           <chr>     <date>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1           AAPL 2007-01-03     86.29     86.58      83.80
2           AAPL 2007-01-04     84.05     85.95      85.66
3           AAPL 2007-01-05     85.77     86.20      85.05
4           AAPL 2007-01-08     85.96     86.53      85.47
5           AAPL 2007-01-09     86.45     92.98      92.57
6           AAPL 2007-01-10     94.75     97.80      97.00
7           AAPL 2007-01-11     95.94     96.78      95.80
8           AAPL 2007-01-12     94.59     95.06      94.62
9           AAPL 2007-01-16     95.68     97.25      97.10
10          AAPL 2007-01-17     97.56     97.60      94.95
# ... with 2,545 more rows, and 2 more variables:
#   AAPL.adjusted <dbl>, AAPL.diff <dbl>

[[2]]
Source: local data frame [2,555 x 7]
Groups: symbol.x [1]

   AAL.symbol.x   AAL.date AAL.open AAL.high AAL.close
          <chr>     <date>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1           AAL 2007-01-03    53.89    56.92     56.30
2           AAL 2007-01-04    56.30    59.15     58.84
3           AAL 2007-01-05    58.83    59.15     58.29
4           AAL 2007-01-08    57.30    60.48     57.93
5           AAL 2007-01-09    59.44    60.20     57.90
6           AAL 2007-01-10    60.03    60.04     58.93
7           AAL 2007-01-11    59.18    61.20     61.20
8           AAL 2007-01-12    61.20    62.50     60.81
9           AAL 2007-01-16    60.81    62.10     61.96
10          AAL 2007-01-17    60.96    61.89     58.65
# ... with 2,545 more rows, and 2 more variables:
#   AAL.adjusted <dbl>, AAL.diff <dbl>
```

Comment: Okay, I got this working and even mutated the tibble into and xts, but I'm doing data training, so I need all symbols as headers.  Can tidyquant do that?                                                                                                  `AAL.Volume AAL.Adjusted
   2007-01-03    2955600     54.80361`
    `2007-01-04    2614500     57.27610`
    `2007-01-05    1656300     56.74072`
    `2007-01-08    2163200     56.39028`
   `2007-01-09    2098600     56.36108`
   `2007-01-10    3892200     57.36371`

Comment: @Alteredorange, see updated solution. Is this what you meant by "symbols in headers" ?

Comment: please note that the `tidyquant` package has been updated. The column name "symbol.x" will now be "symbol". This was changed in v0.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do when I use `quantmod`s `getSymbols` function, is to write my own small wrapper-function, something along this:

```
library(quantmod)
# 1. write the wrapper function
my_wrapper <- function(tickers, from, to) {
  result_list <- lapply(tickers, function(ticker) {
    tmp <- getSymbols(ticker, from = from, to = to, auto.assign = F)
    tmp_df <- data.frame(date = index(tmp), 
                         ticker = ticker,
                         open = as.numeric(Op(tmp)), 
                         high = as.numeric(Hi(tmp)), 
                         close = as.numeric(Cl(tmp)),
                         adj = as.numeric(Ad(tmp)))
  })

  result_df <- do.call(rbind, result_list)
  return(result_df)
}

# 2. download and inspect the data
my_df <- my_wrapper(c("AAPL", "AAL"), from = "2010-01-01", to = "2016-12-31")
summary(my_df)
# date             ticker          open             high            close             adj         
# Min.   :2010-01-04   AAPL:1762   Min.   :  3.99   Min.   :  4.06   Min.   :  4.00   Min.   :  3.894  
# 1st Qu.:2011-09-30   AAL :1762   1st Qu.: 17.16   1st Qu.: 17.46   1st Qu.: 17.23   1st Qu.: 16.770  
# Median :2013-07-04               Median : 72.94   Median : 73.45   Median : 73.02   Median : 41.920  
# Mean   :2013-07-02               Mean   :168.48   Mean   :170.10   Mean   :168.40   Mean   : 49.208  
# 3rd Qu.:2015-04-06               3rd Qu.:318.11   3rd Qu.:320.39   3rd Qu.:318.23   3rd Qu.: 72.969  
# Max.   :2016-12-30               Max.   :702.41   Max.   :705.07   Max.   :702.10   Max.   :127.966
```

Then, to calculate the differences I would suggest using `dplyr` or `data.table` or some other data-frame manipulation package. Here I use dplyr.

```
# 3. Calculate the difference using dplyr
library(dplyr)

my_rets <- my_df %>% group_by(ticker) %>% mutate(pd = (high - open) / open)

my_rets
# Source: local data frame [3,524 x 7]
# Groups: ticker [2]
# 
#         date ticker   open   high  close      adj           pd
#        <date> <fctr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1  2010-01-04   AAPL 213.43 214.50 214.01 27.72704 0.0050133440
# 2  2010-01-05   AAPL 214.60 215.59 214.38 27.77498 0.0046132153
# 3  2010-01-06   AAPL 214.38 215.23 210.97 27.33318 0.0039649549
# 4  2010-01-07   AAPL 211.75 212.00 210.58 27.28265 0.0011806659
# 5  2010-01-08   AAPL 210.30 212.00 211.98 27.46403 0.0080837473
# 6  2010-01-11   AAPL 212.80 213.00 210.11 27.22176 0.0009398731
# 7  2010-01-12   AAPL 209.19 209.77 207.72 26.91211 0.0027725991
# 8  2010-01-13   AAPL 207.87 210.93 210.65 27.29172 0.0147206905
# 9  2010-01-14   AAPL 210.11 210.46 209.43 27.13366 0.0016657655
# 10 2010-01-15   AAPL 210.93 211.60 205.93 26.68020 0.0031764188
# # ... with 3,514 more rows
```

P.s. you find a good dplyr introduction here: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html